# Is it possible to check, if adblock is blocking another website?

Tags: javascript, adblock

Hello Is it possible to check on my website if Adblock is blocking another Webpages?

I have some referal links commision but looks like visitors using adblocks and its preventing monetization.
I do checking, if they use adblock on my website, but what about my partners webpages?

Is it possible to verification do on my own page?
I know I can propose whitelists /filters etc. but problem still exists If my page is whitelisted but partners pages doesn't.

My idea is bellow but can be dead end or even not possible:

Using Javascript or Iframes (obsolete) or requests or any other idea?

Comment: Use XmlHttpRequest to attempt to fetch something?

Comment: It is not possible to put one website from one origin in an iframe and check from the parent page from another origin.

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @VLAZ maybe but its good manner to show you did some effort before asking others for help, so I just posted my idea

Comment: You could try loading an image from that other website and see if it exists.

Comment: XY problems waste the time of everybody involved. I wouldn't call that polite or helpful. Especially towards solving the X.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a js file that allows you to intercept the presence of AdBlock Plus on the user's browser and show a message on the screen inviting him to disable it in order to view the pages correctly.

In the web page embed an external javascript file called **advertisement.js**.

Inside the javascript file you can insert a simple instruction to write something on the screen:

```
document.write('<div id="tester">an advertisement</div>');
```

In the Head section of the Html document of the web page, call the just created javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/advertisement.js"></script>
```

Create a CSS rule to inhibit the display of the #tester class from being displayed to users. In the web page insert a code to check if the class #tester is defined :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> if(document.getElementById("tester") !=undefined) {

    document.write('');

    } else {

    document.write("<div style=z-index: 99; position:fixed; top:100px; background-color: #cccccc; height:400px; width:100%;>disable adblock to read this page</div> ");
    
    }

</script>
```

If the #tester class is not defined, the javascript code displays a message inviting the user to disable AdBlock.

Comment: thank you for response. Its good idea but with this I can (and I am doing this) only check adblocking my own webpage. Question is, "can I check adblock blocking other domain webpages using code on my webpage"